# page.$eval('#search', el => el[id].value) working only on selected "id" element

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Looking at puppeteer documentation I found that `page.$eval(selector)` runs `document.querySelector(selector)` within my page : 
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v3.1.0/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args

I am trying to select an option from a dropdown at a certain index position that I am able to get. To find what to do I am using chrome console and wrote the following code that works fine :

```
document.querySelector("select#ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue")[id_ed].value
```

My problem is that when I go to my js file and write the same thing using `page.$eval(selector)` it does work only for the selected option :

```
const dropdowns_V3 = await page.$eval("select#ReportViewerControl_ctl04_ctl03_ddValue", all => all[id_ed].value);
```

For information my dropdown options looks like that and only the selected one got the selected attribute :

```
<option selected="selected" value="f31211ab-3126-46b3-bd8d-87ce0c262348">&lt;Select&nbsp;a&nbsp;Value&gt;</option>

<option value="1000000430">Perimetre&nbsp;1</option>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you trying to do? Are you trying to select an option or to get the value of that option?

Comment: I am trying to get the value of the option so that i can use it to select this option later. I found a workaround using page.evaluate and return document.querySelector(string_in).value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're selecting an option with an specific id, it will behave exactly how it is behaving.
You can, by the way, use the

```js
const value = await page.evaluate(() => {
  innerValue = document.querySelector('your selector here').value;

  return innerValue;
});
```

- 

**EDIT**: Whenever you're dealing with the dom content itself, such as getting the `innerText` of a tag or the value of a selector, and not performing actions, like typing or clicking, preferably use the `evaluate` method because it has better perfomance and it's easier to get exactly what you want in the browser content.

Using the $, $$, $eval, $$eval, etc., will return a complex object and to get what you want you will need to treat it on the node context.

-

**EDIT 2**: If by any other reason you prefer to use the $, $$, $eval or $$eval methods, have in mind that the single $ performs a querySelector() action and the double $ performs a querySelectorAll(). The querySelector only returns the first element that matches your selector, while the querySelectorAll will return all the elements that match your selector. With that said, when you use $ an $eval, you must not use the array index notation, since there's only one element returned